# How to get windows application text control value using control id

Tags: c#

Using SPY++ I got window handle and using it I can get text control value from my code, but when I trying to find this window handle by  application parent handle and control id through  GetDlgItem(handle, ButtonId) function it throws error.

```
const int TextCtrlId = 0x0000E910;
IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in localAll)
{
    if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        ProcessModule pm = GetModule(p);
        if (pm != null && p.MainModule.FileName == fn)
            handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
    }
}
if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    return;
}
GetText getText = new GetText();
Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", handle);
IntPtr hWndButton = GetDlgItem(handle, TextCtrlId);
string myText = getText.GetControlText(hWndButton);
Console.WriteLine("Error Code = {0}", GetLastError());
Console.WriteLine("Iput Window Text !!! = {0}", myText);
```

error code is
ERROR_CONTROL_ID_NOT_FOUND

1421 (0x58D)

Control ID not found.
but when I use direct handle (got it from SPY++) from function GetDlgItem(handle) I got same control id which in SPY++.

Comment: [ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE -—1400 (0x578) — Invalid window handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-).

Comment: I converted control id (ButtonId) value to int because function  GetDlgItem(IntPtr,int) parameters types is IntPtr and int   but I get same error 1400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control ID is different from Windows Handle. What you have is a Windows Handle (HWND).
Historically you could call `GetWindowText()` providing the handle to get the text of the control. But limitations have been imposed on this call (Since Windows XP if I remember well) for security reasons to counter password sniffing. Modern control inspection software depend on advanced techniques such as DLL injection to access controls in other processes with no restrictions (inject code in target process to read the control).

Comment: I tried to get text from my created app using control id and it is possible. Is it possible that limitation connected with given application, and software developer limited do not get control text by control id.

Comment: As I said for security reasons Windows XP and later started to prevent a process reading text from another process. To accomplish what you want you'll need to work around these system restrictions. A usual way is code injection in target process to read from within that process. You can refer to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces as an example of accomplishing that. Note these methods are workarounds that employ OS mechanisms in ways they weren't intended for so they have some "hacky" nature.

Comment: Also there might be some anti-malware/security software out there that monitors such activity and stops it. I would think well before including such functionality in a production app.